Ngb-bootstrap alert close button style is not apply properly
I'm working on an Angular project that uses the ngb-alert to show alerts. My alert is working fine, but when I upgrade my Angular version and all other dependencies to the latest, I notice that the close button of the alert is jacked up.
<ngb-alert [type]="'success'" (closed)="onAlertClosed();">
    Text of alert
</ngb-alert>


Here is what I am using
angular- 18.2.8
ngboostrap - 13.1.1
Bootstrap - 4.5.3
I already checked with style overlapping and missing dependencies.

please explain your question with a screenshot of what is wrong, also check the official docs, if there also its the same issue, it a change in the framework styles and its expected. If possible a stackblitz with the issue happening

@NarenMurali I edit the main answer with picture. Please check now

please replicate stackblitz and share back

@NarenMurali I can't replicate in stackblitz as It's a version mismatch issue.

You say you have upgraded all other dependencies but you are still using NgbBootstrap 13.x.x and Bootstrap 4.x.x, these also need to be updated to 17.x.x and 5.3.2 respectively in order to support Angular 18.
The cleanest and easiest way to do this to manually uninstall all NgbBootstrap and Bootstrap packages and then use ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap which should handle the installation of all relevant packages correctly.
If the issue still persists once you have done this then please provide an update (it could potentially be just a missing or renamed icon).

Yes, I tried this as well.
But I got the below error
./src/assets/scss/style.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: theme-color(primary) is not a color.
╷
201 │ $input-group-addon-bg: rgba(theme-color(primary), .08);
│                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\assets\scss_variables.scss 201:24  @import
src\assets\scss\style.scss 7:9          root stylesheet


nuke your node_modules' folder and use npm cito reinstall as per package lock. 2. Check your imports in your styles.scss file; as far as I am aware you should have a single import for bootstrap css that is:@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`


What I understand about issue is like. I use the NobleUI theme and this theme is compatible with angular 14 version. I update the angular version to the latest 18 version.
Now I upgrade the bootstrap version also but got the theme error. Please provide me a solution for this

Sorry I am unable to help further - you have not mentioned NobleUI until this point and having checked the documentation it ONLY supports Angular 14.
